# Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)' (Swift)

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am trying to search through an array displayed in a tableview and I am following [this](https://github.com/codepath/ios_guides/wiki/Search-Bar-Guide) tutorial, however when I try to call the reloadData() method, I get **Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)'**

Any idea what I'm missing?

Thanks in advance for any tips.
Here's my ListController.swift code:

```
import UIKit

var arrayIndex = 0

class ListController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {


    let data = ["New York, NY", "Los Angeles, CA", "Chicago, IL", "Houston, TX",
                "Philadelphia, PA", "Phoenix, AZ", "San Diego, CA", "San Antonio, TX",
                "Dallas, TX", "Detroit, MI", "San Jose, CA", "Indianapolis, IN",
                "Jacksonville, FL", "San Francisco, CA", "Columbus, OH", "Austin, TX",
                "Memphis, TN", "Baltimore, MD", "Charlotte, ND", "Fort Worth, TX"]

    var filteredData: [String]!

    @IBOutlet var searchBarOutlet: UISearchBar!

    //Table Delegate
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        arrayIndex = indexPath.row
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
    }

    // Table Data Source
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filteredData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // Cell Data Source

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableCell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = filteredData[indexPath.row]


        // Cell Visual Formatting
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.05, green:0.05, blue:0.07, alpha:0)
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Raleway", size: 18)
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.disclosureIndicator

        return cell
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        filteredData = searchText.isEmpty ? data : data.filter { (item: String) -> Bool in
        return item.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil
        }

        let tableView = UITableView()

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "\(titles.count) Definitions"

        filteredData = data

}

}
```

Comment: That's a really bizarre and very misleading error as a result of the line `self.tableView.reloadData()`. Comment out that line and that error goes away. But of course this brings up a whole new set of questions about what you are doing with that line.

Comment: I think you're just missing the `@IBOutlet` for your `tableView`.

Comment: Yeah, that line is causing the error but I need to reload the table data after the text of the search bar changes, otherwise I'd never see the results.

Comment: That was it vacawama, thanks a lot. If you wanna post this as an answer, I can choose it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `@IBOutlet` for your `tableView`.  So when you reference `self.tableView` Swift thinks you are talking about one of the methods that starts with `tableView`.

So, get rid of this line in `searchBar(_:textDidChange:)`:

```
let tableView = UITableView()
```

and add an outlet to your `tableView` and connect it:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

Comment: Make your other outlet `weak` as well: `@IBOutlet weak var searchBarOutlet: UISearchBar!`